# Android : Show a list of color previews and pass associated id from color.xml

Tags: java, android, colors

I am working on an Android application in which I have a list of colors I have inserted in color.xml. These colors are for the notes which is being created from the activity. So, the use-case is the user enters a tag, text and selects a color from the available colors from color.xml.

*Please note, I am not looking for a color-picker as colors are already selected, the user can only choose from these*

So, I would like to show a list of colors to user as a preview in small-box(space left for that) and once its clicked, there will be a drop-down menu showing the names inserted in color.xml and the associated preview.

I have no idea which type of container or what is required to achieve this task.. I will post the available code and the colors. Kindly guide me as to how should I proceed

color.xml : Only the colors which user can have :

```
   <color name="noteAqua">#1abc9c</color>
    <color name="noteBlue">#3498db</color>
    <color name="noteDarkBlue">#34495e</color>
    <color name="noteDeepBlue">#0071c1</color>
    <color name="noteDeepRed">#c00000</color>
    <color name="noteGreen">#2ecc71</color>
    <color name="noteGrey">#95a5a6</color>
    <color name="noteOrange">#e67e22</color>
    <color name="notePink">#ff56bb</color>
    <color name="notePurple">#9b59b6</color>
    <color name="noteRed">#e74c3c</color>
    <color name="noteYellow">#f1c40f</color>
```

create_note.xml : If you guys have android IDE running, you can copy paste the below XML, and you will be able to notice, I have left a gap on top-right, where I would like to insert the list of colors.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="315dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/noteTagAddText"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/noteTextAddText"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.97"
        android:gravity="top" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="191dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/saveNoteString"
            android:id="@+id/createNoteButton"
            android:layout_gravity="right" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="191dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/cancelSaveString"
            android:id="@+id/cancelCreateButton" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

CreateNoteActivity class :

```
public class CreateNoteActivity extends Activity {
 EditText noteTag, noteText;
    Button saveButton, cancelButton;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.edit_note);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            groupAccountId = extras.getLong("groupid");
            canvasId = extras.getInt("canvasid");
            sectionid = extras.getInt("sectionid");
        }

        noteTag = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.noteTagEdit);
     //   noteTag.setText(restNote.getMnotetag());

        noteText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.noteTextEdit);
       // noteText.setText(Html.fromHtml(restNote.getMnotetext()));

        noteText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s){
       //     restNote.setMnotetext(s.toString());
            }
        });


        noteTag.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
             //   restNote.setMnotetag(s.toString());
            }

        });
        saveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveNoteButton);
        cancelButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancelEditButton);
        saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                RestNote saveNote = new RestNote();
          //      saveNote.setMnotecolor(restNote.getMnotecolor());
                saveNote.setMnotetag(noteTag.getText().toString());
                saveNote.setMnotetext(noteText.getText().toString());
           //     saveRestNoteOnServer(restNote);

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),GroupSectionActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("groupid", groupAccountId);
                intent.putExtra("canvasid", canvasId);
                intent.putExtra("sectionid",sectionid);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),GroupSectionActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("groupid", groupAccountId);
                intent.putExtra("canvasid", canvasId);
                intent.putExtra("sectionid",sectionid);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Any help would be nice. Thanks a lot. :-)

*Edit*

Something like the image below and when the user clicks on the image, I get the color id in activity.

[image: Color image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use an ImageView and set the background property to you're colour, like so;

```
<ImageView
     android:layout_width="50dp"
     android:layout_height="50dp"
     android:background="@color/yourcolour"/>
```

Then you can set a click listener on this ImageView and do whatever you like once it has been clicked.

```
yourImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 // do something
            }
        });
```

Comment: I am sorry, I fail to understand, I am looking for a list from which color can be selected. I have updated my main post and added an image at the bottom. Kindly check it out.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the exact question you want answered. Do you not know how to put things in a list?... Or how to automatically select a colour? If you could break down you're question into one sentence that would be brilliant, as right now it seems that you're asking 'how to build an app like this', which can't really be answered. If you pin point the exact question you need answered then I'll gladly help.

Comment: Sure. I want to know how to display a list of colours with small preview and when a colour is clicked then pass that colours code to activity. I hope that's sufficient and not too abstract. Thanks a lot. :-)

Comment: So do you know how to make a list in Android? If not then it's probably best looking at some tutorials on how to make a list as it's not really something which would easily be able to fit into a stack overflow answer. You could look at the Android Developer site here https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html . Or a tutorial site like here https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/android-l-recyclerview-and-cardview-tutorial/156 .

Comment: My first answer will help you with how to display the colours in your created list, you'll just have to display the ImageView inside a 'ViewHolder' you'll know what they are once you've gone through a tutorial.

Comment: Okay, I thought there would be some easier solution for displaying and selecting static colors. List I use mostly for dynamic data.

Comment: You could just create them in your layout although it isn't recommended as view's won't be recycled. To do that just list all of your ImageView's in a LinearLayout and populate them in you're Activity or Fragment with your desired colours, then you can set an onClickListener on each ImageView so you can see if a user has selected it.

Comment: The best thing to do in my opinion would be to create an entirely seperate Activity/Fragment with a list of your colours in it, and call it ColourPickerFragment. You could then startActivityForResult to your colour picker activity/fragment and when the user has selected a colour, set you're result to the colour resource and finish that activity. Then in your previous Activities onActivityResult you'll have the selected colour.

Comment: I would like to do it in the same activity(page), not to navigate. I am not worried about recycling issues as content is static.

Comment: Then just place you're desired ImageViews (like I answered above) into you're desired activity and in the Activity set an OnClickListener onto each ImageView. 

yourImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 // do something
            }
        });

Comment: Ok, I will do that, if there is any problem, I will get back. Thanks a lot my friend.. :-)

Comment: Don't forget to upvote/mark if it works! :) Good luck! I'll edit my answer with the code I pasted to you in the previous comment.